# sbt issues with scala 2.11 on ubuntu

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, sbt

I'm having an issue when I tried uploading my code to an EC2 ubuntu instance. I checked my java version, scala version, and sbt version, and everything SEEMS to be in place, but I'm getting an error that looks like it would be a versioning issue.

here is my build.sbt

```
name := "SentenceParserTimingStudy"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("TimingTester")
unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar")

libraryDependencies += "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-parser" % "3.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.2"

libraryDependencies +=  "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.1-M4" changing()

libraryDependencies += "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.2" artifacts (Artifact("stanford-corenlp", "models"), Artifact("stanford-corenlp"))
```

I checked my java and scala version and they seem to be correct

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)    
Scala code runner version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

However whenever I run my code I get this error

```
[error] error while loading <root>, Error accessing /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/cache/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/jars/stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar
    scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)
        at xsbt.CachedCompiler0$$anon$2.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:106)
        at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:106)
        at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:95)
        at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:101)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:51)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:51)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:51)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:75)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
        at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:65)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:66)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:64)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:31)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:62)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:61)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:89)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:61)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:54)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInternal(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:128)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:114)
        at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:829)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:820)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:818)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [error] (compile:compileIncremental) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. You have both `lib/stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar` and `stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar` (in the last line), which probably conflict. However, I don't see why it would give _this_ error. 2. Is there a reason you are compiling the code there instead of compiling on your machine and uploading the result?

Comment: hmm.... that's a good point actually... are you suggesting that I use assembly or something similar and then run the JAR on the EC2 instance? The main reason I'm trying to avoid running this program on my computer is it heats my my computer a LOT, so I'm just trying to avoid causing damage

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.